# How to read one line at a time by using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, usart

I'm facing problem while I'm trying read data from COM port I don't know what is the problem.. here is the code which I'm using to send and receive data through com port.The com port is connected to STM32 board which sends data to be displayed to com port.. I'm appending '\n' at the end of string which is to be displayed. so here is the code

```
import serial

ser.port = "COM4"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
ser.isOpen()

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.'

while 1:
    input = raw_input()
    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        ser.write(input.encode('ascii')+'\r')
        out = ''

        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.readline()

            print  out
```

This is the expected output

```
Different commands offered are as follows: 
''dis''                 Displays contact list
''crt name number''     To create contact list
''del name''                To delete contact details
''edt existingName newName number''      To edit contact details
''clog''                    To display calllog details
''cin''                 Displays only incoming call details
''cout''                    Displays only outgoing call details
''cmis''                    Displays only missed call details
''rvc number''          To receive a call
''mkc number''          To make a call
''mkc name''                To call from contact list
''clogc number''            To call from calllog list
''cdel''                    To delete callLog details
```

But I'm getting this
http://s15.postimg.org/sg9pvr20r/Untitled.jpg
sorry i can't paste total output so I've included screenshot of my output..

Comment: where do you open your connection?

Comment: It's direct ... After configuring we can write to port just by using ser.write()

Comment: sure, I was just expecting some `ser = serial.Serial()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `print out` statement is inside your `while`-loop, it is being called multiple times. If I get your desired output correctly this is not what you want - unindent `print out` to put it outside your `while`-loop and you're fine:

```
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += ser.readline()
print  out
```

Answer (score 0):

`serial.readline()` accepts only '\n' as a line separator, and it waits until newline (unless `serial.timeout` different from `None` was explicitly specified). So I would go for a simpler loop:

```
while True:
    out = ser.readline()
    if not out or out == "exit":
        break
    print out
```

`serial.inWaiting()` returns the number of symbols in the input buffer, which does not seem to matter in this case.

Comment: But my COM port sends one character at a time so i need to store all the character in variable and then display it...

Comment: readline() does it for you, it accumulates chars in an internal buffer until a newline ('\n') arrives, and then returns you the whole bunch. The call is blocking, so your program/thread does nothing until the whole line is accumulated. I would also expect explicit `ser = serial.Serial()`.

Comment: what i should do if i'm sending multiple lines appended with '\n'?  do i need to send number lines that i'm going send first so that i can read that many lines..

Comment: There is a loop in my example that reads line by line. The variable `out` contains one line (without the trailing '\n') at each iteration, so your code should be prepared to deal with one line at a time. I presume the exchange protocol with STM32 to be text-based and line-oriented, hence the `readline()`. A description of the data sent by STM32 is needed for any further recommendations.